# Read C# method code within [EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]?

Tags: c#

I am reading some C# project code and see a public method being marked as:

```
[EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)]
```

It looks like a good portion of that method code isn't viewable to me.

Is there a way to see the code within that method?

Comment: I can't view the actual C# code within that method (which is marked with  EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Advanced)].

Comment: Basically can't see anything within the method. Not sure if I miss anything.

Comment: Actually your first link answers my question. thanks!